# stop yii2 redirect on "option" click "MultiSelect"

Tags: jquery, yii2

I'm using YII2 gridview with a dropdown multiselect widget ("2amigos/yii2-multi-select-widget").

in a normal Dropdown (single select) yii2 does the expected behavior for the "onClick" event for every single option, which is redirecting to the new "filtered model".

but now since I'm using a "MultiSelect" this behavior prevents you from selecting multiple options.

How/where can I  unbind the click event on "option" and make it on "Dropdown" closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to circumvent my problem, I deactivated the GridView filter and created my own filter that will feed the Search class.